# Status(UP/DOWN) of Session based Application hosted on Tomcat server in UNIX

Tags: scripting, curl, monitoring, authentication, tomcat

I need to check the status (UP/DOWN) of an application (https://w45ra0377.abc.com:12345) that is hosted on a server in UNIX.
This is a session authenticated application.

I tried with the below CURL command, but dint got any result since there is no session.

```
curl -X GET "https://w45ra0377.abc.com:12345/actuator/health"
```

Can anyone suggest how to get the status (UP/DOWN) of a session-based application?

Comment: What do you mean by "session based application"? Do you need to authenticate? What do you mean by "status"? HTTP Status code? Edit your question to elaborate, it is unclear what you're asking in its current form

Comment: edited the question. I need to get the status of session authenticated application hosted on the server (UP/DOWN).